# How can I get Vue.js 3 to use the vue-google-oauth2 package?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-oauth, vuejs3

The following code

```
const app = createApp(App);

const gauthOptions = {
    clientId: CLIENTID,
    scope: SCOPES,
    prompt: 'select_account'
};

app.use(GAuth, gauthOptions);
```

Throws this error

> "Object.defineProperties called on a non-object".

In the docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-oauth2) in place of app.use() they have the global Vue.use(). I understand createApp in Vue3 was abstracted to solve some globalisation issues, but I'm wondering now does that break the functionality of this gauth package (that was built for vue), or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

Using `app.use(...)` instead of `Vue.use(...)` doesn't solve the issue since this module has not supported vue 3 yet, regarding to the last [releases](https://github.com/guruahn/vue-google-oauth2/releases) there's no vue 3 support mention, you could also there's this [issue](https://github.com/guruahn/vue-google-oauth2/issues/47) asking about how to use this module with Vue 3 which hasn't received any comment yet.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of. Alright thanks, back to the drawing board

Comment: these libraries should release new versions that support vue 3, but you can also take advantage of some vue 3 features like composition api by using its plugin in vue 2

Comment: going to try and build my own implementation from here https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs

Comment: Good, if that works for you, try to post an answer that explains it

Comment: I'll try, but don't know if I am capable of reverse engineering the package to figure out exactly what is going wrong with it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There is a new implementation for Vue3 available!

[NPM Vue3-google-oauth2](https://github.com/guruahn/vue3-google-oauth2)